# Remove the first results in the search result web part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, search-results

I have a page where I got two search result webparts listing articles.

I want the first webpart to display the first two articles (main articles), and the other webpart to display article 3 to 10.

All of this is easily done, apart from the predefined pagination in my article list.

Is it easy to remove the first results in the search result web part? I do not want to start programming, this have to be done with webparts. And I have to use search result webpart to display the articles, I've done lot of customization to the display templates.

Anybody got any tips?

Answer (score 0):

StartRow and RowLimit are supported, though I haven't looked to see if they are supported in the OOB Web parts.

Comment: You can use startrow and all of the other paging-commands if you do some programming, but as far as I can see, not out of box. I hoped there was a way circumventing this :)